# Python: How do I assign the indexes of an item in a 2D list to two integer variables?

Tags: python

So I found out how to find the indexes of an item in a 2D list in Python by using this code:

```
def index_2d(myList, v):
    for i, x in enumerate(myList):
        if v in x:
            return (i, x.index(v))
```

Usage:

```
index_2d(myList, 3)
#Result (1, 0)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5775397/8233898)

I want the output to be in two variables (like x = 1, y = 0). How can I do this?

Comment: It _is_ returning two values. You can capture them like this: `x,y = index_2d(...)`

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python) for more information about that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you can return more than one value using tuples.

```
def f():
    return (1,2,3)

(x, y, z) = f()
```

In a more pythonic way to do it, you can only separate the values with ',' to indicate that it is a tuple.

```
x, y, z = f()
```